# Rails: how to include Rack::Utils

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I follow rails convention [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide): That we shouldn't use directly error code but its symbol. For example:

```
# bad
...
render status: 500
...

# good
...
render status: :forbidden
...
```

But in fact, those number hasn't been declared yet, so if I want to use I must use as:

```
Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:bad_request]
```

This is messy. My question is: how can I include/extend module `Rake::Utils` so I only need use `:bad_request`

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 4.2.5.1 from rails console, doing:

`Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:bad_request]` I get `400`

Doing `Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE`. I can see all this statuses...

```
{
 :continue=>100,
 :switching_protocols=>101,
 :processing=>102,
 :ok=>200,
 :created=>201,
 :accepted=>202,
 :non_authoritative_information=>203,
 :no_content=>204,
 :reset_content=>205,
 :partial_content=>206,
 :multi_status=>207,
 :already_reported=>208,
 :im_used=>226,
 :multiple_choices=>300,
 :moved_permanently=>301,
 :found=>302,
 :see_other=>303,
 :not_modified=>304,
 :use_proxy=>305,
 :temporary_redirect=>307,
 :permanent_redirect=>308,
 :bad_request=>400,
 :unauthorized=>401,
 :payment_required=>402,
 :forbidden=>403,
 :not_found=>404,
 :method_not_allowed=>405,
 :not_acceptable=>406,
 :proxy_authentication_required=>407,
 :request_timeout=>408,
 :conflict=>409,
 :gone=>410,
 :length_required=>411,
 :precondition_failed=>412,
 :payload_too_large=>413,
 :uri_too_long=>414,
 :unsupported_media_type=>415,
 :range_not_satisfiable=>416,
 :expectation_failed=>417,
 :unprocessable_entity=>422,
 :locked=>423,
 :failed_dependency=>424,
 :upgrade_required=>426,
 :precondition_required=>428,
 :too_many_requests=>429,
 :request_header_fields_too_large=>431,
 :internal_server_error=>500,
 :not_implemented=>501,
 :bad_gateway=>502,
 :service_unavailable=>503,
 :gateway_timeout=>504,
 :http_version_not_supported=>505,
 :variant_also_negotiates=>506,
 :insufficient_storage=>507,
 :loop_detected=>508,
 :not_extended=>510,
 :network_authentication_required=>511
}
```

I think you don't need to define any new status.
If you need to do it anyway, you can add it using an initializer:

*/my_app/config/initializers/codes.rb*

`Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:my_code] = 666`

Then in a controller:

```
class Api::V1::RegionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    respond_with Region.all, status: :my_code
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm returning the custom code.

[image: postman example returning custom code]

Comment: thanks. It looks like we can use directly code inside controller. But I want to use  `:my_code` at random files. For specifically, I want to use in file that extends from `Grape::API`.

Comment: well, that was not the question...I think you can use create your own method to use `Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE`

Comment: thanks. I have thought about using "include/extend" but it seems not work ;(